# Dynamics 365 Word Template XML Content Control field with Quick Part field formatting like DisplayBarcode?

Tags: ms-word, microsoft-dynamics, mailmerge

I have a Microsoft Word template document from Dynamics 365 with XML Mapping fields for information about a customer. This works great for filling out text, but the Content Control fields do not refresh when inside a QuickPart field. This means they can't be used with the DisplayBarcode QuickPart field, and the value stays as the name of the field instead of the value from XML.

Is there a way to allow the content in the XML mapping fields to be manipulated by standard Word mail merge tools like this QR code example?

For example, this Word template for a library borrowers' card:

**Name: [BorrowerName ContentControl]**

**Borrower ID: [CardID Content Control]**

**{DisplayBarcode "[CardID Content Control] QR}**

Will display this when opened with XML mapping data:

**Name: John Citizen**

**Borrower ID: ABC123**

**QR Code with data "CardID Content Control" (field name, not expected value ABC123)**